# Define Silex Cron job

Tags: cron, task, silex

How to add a cron job in a Silex PHP Server?
I would like to do some tasks every midnights without a previous user request. I know we can use middleware functions in order to execute some tasks after and before a Request, but I would like to do without one of them.

I just follow some samples which use [ConsoleServiceProvice](https://blog.kendepelchin.be/2014/01/19/using-consoleserviceprovider-with-silex/) but, although code doesn't show any error, the execute method is never call. And, it is not a cron task.

So, Is it possible to define a Cron job in Silex 1.x??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want manage your crontask withiout crotab from console
you can use this Cron Task MAnager
[github.com/MUlt1mate/cron-manager](https://github.com/MUlt1mate/cron-manager)
Simple install with composer

Answer (score 1):

You can define a console command in silex, but you'll need a task scheduler to actually run in when you want. Cron is perfect for this!

If you want it to run every midnight, type `crontab -e` in a terminal and put this in the file:

```
0 0 * * * <command you want to run>
```

For more details on crontab formatting, see [`man crontab`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).

This is the simplest way, there are more tips and tricks to using cron, do read up on the subject!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But How execute the crontask in a silex app?

Comment: You add it to your crontab, like I said in my answer.